# Gnome software devours memory in 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-software

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 a few days ago.

`Gnome-shell` was eating up my memory (somewhere around 13% according to `top`and climbing), so I started looking for solutions online. I opened up `Settings` to check my gnome version, and as soon as I did, my computer ground down to a halt.

After 15 minutes of waiting for the terminal to open up, it finally did, I managed to write in `top`, and after about 5 minutes I saw that `gnome-software` had taken up over half of my available memory (56%).  In a painstaking process that took another 10 minutes I managed to write `sudo kill -9 PID`, and free up my computer. My relief lasted only for about a minute before my laptop slowed down to a crawl again. At that point I rebooted.

What do I do about gnome-software? How can I fix this?

Comment: You're talking about RAM usage in terms of percentage... what does this work out to in absolute terms? How much RAM do you have?

Also, we might infer what it is you're after, but not for nothing, you don't actually ask a question at any point in your post.

Comment: I have 8 GBs of physical ram

Comment: Thanks; just making sure you weren't in a very low RAM situation before thinking about this.

Comment: I've had to deal with some similar issues in the past, though not with GNOME specifically. Sometimes when you are shocked by software's high memory usage, it's intentional, but this doesn't sound like such a situation. In that case you want to check out bug reports to see if anyone else is facing a similar problem (which they usually will be). [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1616332) might be related to your particular situation.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1616332